# Systemctl httpd.service file changed on disk

Tags: fedora, systemd, apache-httpd, systemctl

When start `httpd` with systemctl, I get the error:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of httpd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

I run `systemctl daemon-reload` and the error persists.

Here is the output of `systemctl status httpd`:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of httpd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-05-29 08:08:09 CDT; 4min 6s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 19471 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 80"
    Tasks: 213 (limit: 4500)
   Memory: 18.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─19471 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─19472 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─19473 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─19474 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─19475 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

What can I do to further diagnose the problem?

Running Fedora 28, systemd 238, and apache 2.4.34.

Comment: Well for starters you can help answerers by [edit]ing the version of systemd and the version of Fedora into the question.

Comment: Take a look at `journalctl -e`, particularly after `systemctl daemon-reload`, to see if perhaps any errors are being reported at that point...

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/php-fpm.conf` a symlink to a file that might be changing regularly by any chance? Check the timestamps of the config files involved... Maybe something *is* changing them regularly, so the warning is indeed accurate?

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger The only thing is ``systemd[1]: Reloading.``` The file is an actual file with the contents: ```[Unit] Wants=php-fpm.service``` would this be redirecting the config file?

Comment: @Jersh No, so far everything looks normal... It's a puzzler.

Comment: This should not be systemd bug #3123 then.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The date was off on my server compared to the `overides.conf` file. So I just did a `touch overides.conf`. That was located in `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d`.

Apparently `systemctl daemon-reload` will not work as intended if the date is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem.  I had a unit named `foo-1.2.3` and it is enabled as `systemctl enable foo-1.2.3`, so that it creates an alias named just `foo` without the version number.

When I did `systemctl edit foo`, it created an override file named `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/override.conf`, and then I kept getting the "hanged on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units" message over and over, even if I did run daemon-reload.

I renamed the directory to `/etc/systemd/system/foo-1.2.3.service.d`, i.e. not using the alias, and the error message went away.  There were no clues at all in `journalctl`.  I feel like this is a bug.  If systemd doesn't like using aliases to the `edit` command, it should fail early.  Or the override directory should be consistently named, not using the alias.

That said, systemd is still not honoring the override file! I'm setting an env var in the override file, and the process is not getting that env var.  I still have debugging to do...